# Do we have any responsibility to take any action if someone says they're thinking about suicide in their post?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

There's a post that was closed as off-topic, which it is. It's a rant, one that definitely doesn't fit within the scope of our site.

The author of the post mentions he's contemplating suicide. Is there anything that we should do in these situations? Amy makes a great point that it would be a shame if that did indeed happen, but we also shouldn't keep the post open just because someone is having a bad day.

It seems odd though that a site about conceptual questions in the field of Software Engineering has to deal with such a question, but it's something that's worth discussion to get everyone on the same page.

What should we do if someone is threatening suicide? Is it our responsibility to intervene? Should the post be locked so folks don't do more harm than good by posting inflammatory comments (not that that's happened)?

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/216389/i-am-not-satisfied-with-my-career-and-accomplished-nothing-in-my-life-what-shou

Comment: There's actually an [Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51461/mental-fitness) that was launched to help with this subject.

Comment: similar discussion at MSE: [What's the official SE response to serious mentions of suicide in posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243700/whats-the-official-se-response-to-serious-mentions-of-suicide-in-posts)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I hate to sound callous about this, but... This isn't a support group; y'all probably aren't trained to deal with the outpouring of grief and despair of someone you've never met and may have absolutely nothing in common with. I'm certainly not. Indeed, there's a decent chance that leaving a post like this around could end up just making things *worse*.

Therefore, I strongly recommend the following:

1. Close the post as Off Topic, with a comment like this:

   > It sounds like you're going through a really hard time. I'd really like to help you, but unfortunately, we're not well-equipped to do so here. Your best option is probably to call the National Suicide Prevention Lifeline. People are on call there to talk to people struggling with the same kind of issues you are, regardless of location. US: +1-800-273-8255. If calling's not good, they can chat with you live online. Just go to this site, and you can talk with someone online from 10PM-6AM UTC: http://suicidepreventionlifeline.org/GetHelp/LifelineChat.aspx It might not help, but what's the harm?
2. Flag for a moderator who can lock or delete the question to prevent discussion from continuing in the comments.
3. For *any* credible threat of bodily harm - whether targeted at the author themselves or someone else - use the **contact us** option at the bottom of any page on the site to let us know about this. If need-be, we'll follow up to make sure the situation is handled appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for handling this. I wasn't quite sure how to deal with this and now I know.

Comment: I agree with this. Is there a SE site that actually **is** akin to a support group that we could redirect the question to that may be better equipped?

Comment: No, @Telastyn; this is [an outstandingly poor tool](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167642/what-is-stack-exchange-not-good-for) for that job.

Comment: That answer is very US centric. Maybe a page exist with list of suicide hotlines around the world that we could use instead?

Comment: If you can find one, add it @bjarkef. That said, the organization referenced is open to contact from any location.

Comment: @bjarkef In the early days of Quora, something similar happened. The person was definitely NOT a resident of the USA, as he said which continent he lived on, even though the question was submitted anonymously. We worried, responded to his question, tried to help, perhaps did help, but ultimately, I think what Shog9 suggested would have been best. Quora is, or was, Q&A with some social, whereas SO is Q&A with minimal social. Even if SO were Q&A with a lot of social, it would be difficult. Being US-centric adds further complexity that is beyond what an SE site can do, responsibly.

Comment: And 'distress vampires' exist too. I've heard about cases of people 'dying of cancer' on health forums, and milking all the virtual sympathy, and it all turning out to be hokum. Doing what @Shog9 says insulates us from that too.

Comment: For what it's worth, @FeralOink, the BBC forums, which definitely *are* social spaces, have the same policy (or, at least, did a few years ago when last I checked). Suicide mentions should be flagged for moderator attention. Of course, the Beeb has trained mods on staff to deal with this stuff. I'm not sure that SE does.

Comment: @EllieKesselman, Which thread was it? Do you have a link?

Comment: @Pacerier I will look now. Quora's search isn't as good as SE sites :o) so I might be awhile.

Comment: @EllieKesselman, Usually Google's search works better (same for SE's case). E.g. google `quora *search-term*`.

Comment: Moderators these days should ping the team directly from the user's profile, rather than using the contact form.

Comment: Why should such a post be locked? Immediate deletion, never undelete the post! Also, staff attention is good for suicidal posts.